Google Sheets not showing the last column in full
I have a couple  of sheets that won't scroll all the way to the right to display the last column in full. I have tried adding in columns beside it & adjusting the width.
This sheet is using the importrange function to pull live data from another sheet & it happens on the original & on the live copy. The original sheet is using an array formula to pull data from a form submission sheet (so that I can format it).
It doesn't happen to all my sheets just a few.
I have tried making new copies, adjusting the column width, adding in new columns after (it just cuts those off too), refreshing, & restarting my computer.
